# Getting SerializationException when running add-migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, autofac

add-migration v3_80 -ConnectionStringName MyMigrations 
yields me a serializationException Type is not resolved for member 'Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException,Autofac, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=17863af14b0044da'

I have looked through solutions and there seem to be 2 known possibilities.  One being an ampersand in a directory name and another being some of the projects being a different .Net version.  I have verified I have no ampersands and all projects are version 4.6.1.  Not sure where to go now to resolve this error.

Here is output with verbose
    PM> add-migration v3_80 -ConnectionStringName MyMigrations -Verbose
Using StartUp project 'Nop.Plugin.Misc.HuntNBuddies'.
Using NuGet project 'Nop.Plugin.Misc.HuntNBuddies'.
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type is not resolved for member 'Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException,Autofac, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=17863af14b0044da'.
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Scaffold(String migrationName, String language, String rootNamespace, Boolean ignoreChanges)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddMigrationCommand.Execute(String name, Boolean force, Boolean ignoreChanges)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddMigrationCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
Type is not resolved for member 'Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException,Autofac, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=17863af14b0044da'.
PM>

Comment: could you try running the command with the -Verbose flag ? and edit your post with the complete log output

Answer (score 1):

This error message is a known bug in Entity Framework and is fixed in 6.2. I have a workaround to figure out what is wrong that I answered here:

[New embedded Firebird, code first, EF6 project results in SerializationException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34959584/new-embedded-firebird-code-first-ef6-project-results-in-serializationexception/40248509#40248509)

Comment: This helped me find the error.  With the Entity Framework 6.2, it actually gave me the inner error that was occurring and I was able to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

- Go to nuget packet manager
- go to consolidate tab
- Consolidate all your packages to the correct version

Sometimes nuget packages target a different version making errors like this hard to solve. I hope this fixes it

Comment: I ran the consolidate packages and still get the error.